# Custom Initializer when ViewController is loaded from NibFile

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a UISplitViewController in a xib file that contains two custom UIViewControllers. I put most of my initialization code in the viewDidLoad: method, but I don't think thats where it should be.

What method can I override so that my code will be run when the xib is inflated?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if you require any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [- (void)awakeFromNib](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Another option is [-(id)initWithCoder:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCoding/initWithCoder%3a) but I would recommend the awakeFromNib.

> An awakeFromNib message is sent to each object loaded from the
>   archive, but only if it can respond to the message, and only after all
>   the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an
>   object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all
>   its outlet instance variables set.

Comment: Easy question, easy answer. Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: If the initialization items you are reffering is view related (adding views, changing frames, or colors) I would recommend keeping that in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I am just initializing DataSources for my table view. But I do understand what you are saying. Thanks for the advice.